Ubuntu 24.04.1 with Ryzen 5 5500U randomly freezes when the VScode and Google Chrome is open
The issue that I'm currently having never happened when using previous 22.04 LTS. I looked in the syslog, but did not find anything pertaining to the issue. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?
System Info
Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              HP HP Laptop 17-cp0xxx
Memory:                                      8.0 GiB
Processor:                                   AMD Ryzen™ 5 5500U with Radeon™ Graphics × 12
Graphics:                                    AMD Radeon™ Graphics
Disk Capacity:                               256.1 GB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            F.24
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-41-generic

